# Design a Relation Ships For Data Warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I'm going to design a DataWarehouse for Northwind Database, but my customer and product and employee tables have two common fields called country and city.
I want to find out that it is correct to define the relationship between dimension Geo and 3 Other Dimensions according to the diagram form?
If you have any comments please share

[My DataWareHouse Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvtHa.png)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what phylosophy you want to implement. If you follow Kimball you want a star schema, where fact tables are connected to dimensions and those don’t connect to anything else. In that case you’re better off keeping the geo fields in each dimension.

Any redundancy is meaningless as normally all dimensions combined are much smaller in size than the fact table(s), probably a few percentage points of the whole size.

On the other hand, joining 3 tables in a chain is much more expensive than a single join.

Saving CPU and query time calculations at the expense of a few more bytes (or kilobytes, or megabytes) is usually a good trade off.

Comment: So according to your explanation if I understood correctly
I have to bring Geokey into every Dimension of Employee, Customers, Products with lookUp Component, instead of the design that I brought GeoID into every Dimension.
Am I right?

Comment: No, you should actually bring country, city and any other geo field directly into every dimension, so that if you need, e.g., sales by customer country you only need a simple join between fact table and dimension. Reccommended reading: The Data Warehouse Toolkit, Ralph Kimball